# Starting java processes with Upstart

Tags: java, upstart

I want to start a java process using Upstart. Currently, on our OpenSuSE servers, I use the System V init system to achieve this, but on our Ubuntu servers I'd rather use Upstart. But I have two questions...

I have an Upstart job (a task) that configures the server, called, say, myconfig.
And in the job that starts my java processes I ostensibly have:

```
start on stopped myconfig
exec /path/to/myjavastartscript.sh
```

myjavastartscript.sh runs 'java -classpath blah MyClass'. In System V init, starting the service runs 'nohup /path/to/myjavastartscript.sh &'.

So my first question is whether I still need to do the nohup or run-in-background with the exec command?

When running, MyClass starts other Java processes. In System V init, the service stop just looks for java processes owned by a certain user and kills them. My second question is how could I control the termination of these processes with Upstart?

Answer (score 4):

You do not need to use `nohup` since when Upstart runs a program, that process will not be associated with a terminal (by default).

For Upstart, I'd suggest either just having the job call:

```
exec java -classpath blah MyClass
```

... or ensuring that /path/to/myjavastartscript.sh calls:

```
exec java -classpath blah MyClass
```

Note that the first `exec` above is an Upstart stanza whereas the 2nd is a shell keyword.
If your shell script does not call the shell version of `exec`, you'll need to be careful to ensure you set the Upstart `expect` stanza correctly - see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#expect.

Regarding stopping the service, Upstart will automatically kill the process it is tracking (the main JVM process associated with `MyClass`) and any children of that process (technically any process in the same process group (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stopping-a-job)).

Without more details, I'm not sure your `start on` condition is suitable - presumably, you want the MyClass job start if and only if a configuration file has been setup? If so, the standard idiom is for the jobs `pre-start` stanza to read in `/etc/default/MyClass.conf`. If it decides that either the file doesn't exist, or the config file somehow indicates that the service is disabled / not setup correctly, the `pre-start` can simply call `stop` to stop the job from (fully) starting (see http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#pre-start). The advantage of this approach being that your `start on` condition can then be reliably set to whatever set of conditions should cause the job to start. When those conditions are met, Upstart will run the job; the pre-start will run, determine the configuration is not yet valid and simply exit. The day the admin does decide to configure the service, the job will fully start.

See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#determining-the-start-on-condition-ubuntu-specific and http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#ubuntu-well-known-events-ubuntu-specific for determining the `start on` condition.

Note finally that you should really always specify a `stop on` condition too. See http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#stop-on.

Comment: You statement `exec java -classpath blah MyClass` is repeated twice without a change.

Comment: @MuhammadGelbana I believe that is on purpose. See his explanation in the following paragraph.

Comment: `exec` inside the start scripts works like a charm :) I wish I had known about it sooner, so I wouldn't have had to write the following monstrosity for a past project: `java ...; JAVAPID=$!; trap "kill $JAVAPID" exit INT TERM; wait`

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem, wanting to start the serviio dlna server when booting my machine.

This is my `/etc/init/serviio.conf`:

```
description "Start serviio DLNA server"
author "aanno"

start on net-device-up IFACE=eth0
stop on runlevel [!2345]
env enabled=1

setuid tpasch
setgid tpasch

#respawn the process if it crashes
respawn

env SERVIIO_HOME=/home/tpasch/serviio-1.0.1
script
        [ "$enabled" = "1" ] || [ "$force_start" = "1" ] || exit 0
        # Setup Serviio specific properties
        JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dderby.system.home=$SERVIIO_HOME/library -Dserviio.home=$SERVIIO_HOME -Xmx512M -Xms20M -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=10 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=20"

        # construct classpath
        cd $SERVIIO_HOME
        CLASSPATH="config"

        for i in lib/*.jar; do
                CLASSPATH="$CLASSPATH:$i"
        done

        exec /usr/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -classpath $CLASSPATH org.serviio.MediaServer
end script
```

Comment: I'm getting this error when I add the `for` loop: `/proc/self/fd/9: 9: /proc/self/fd/9: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting "do")`. I'm having the loop the same as you mentioned it here. Thank you.