# Starting and stopping of applications

Tags: scripts

I need to make my restart process lesser commands. I dont want to code anything or create a `service`. So I created 2 scripts to do that. But even then the process is too lengthy. Is there a way to kill the application without the process id OR a way to kill the process with just one command.

Start Script

```
nohup memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -U 11211 -l IPA 2>&1 > $1memcached.log &
sleep 2
nohup java -classpath mCruiseOnServer_lib/ -jar mCruiseOnServer.jar >&1 > $1mcruiseon.log &
```

Check Process Id's (and manually call kill -9)

```
ps -ef | grep java
ps -ef | grep memcached
```

Comment: Combine this with a .pid/.lock file if you really must http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/108369-process-id-exe-started-nohup.html

Comment: What do you mean, faster? As in, less commands to type, or less time to execute? What is taking up all this time currently? It sounds like you do want to create a service. Too bad that's randomly assigned to " I don't wan't to do that"... memcached allready has a service afaik, so I'm not sure why you don't use that? You could also run your other script without the '&' in a screen, so you can just ctrl-c it? (mind you, that's an awkward 'sullution' i'd not support)

Comment: Thanks for the language feedback, fixed it. Good idea on memcached, thanks. And without the & is a good idea, but as you said, its not the right way to run a backend service that you need running for ages.

Comment: @CallmeV exploring the idea. Will report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you so against services? **This is exactly what they're for!**

- The repo-packaged `memcached` ships with an init.d service that can be controlled and monitored through `sudo /etc/init.d/memcached {start|stop|restart|force-reload|status}`
- And it's pretty simple to write an Upstart script for a Java program:

  - [Starting java processes with Upstart](https://askubuntu.com/a/194808/449)

  That gives you `sudo start|stop|status myjob` access.

Comment: Trying this out. Will report back in a while.