# Automate starting and stopping of programs from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have been trying to make it easier and faster to start and stop programs from terminal but didn't get anywhere. Closest thing I found on my searches is this:
[Starting and stopping of applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/290426/starting-and-stopping-of-applications)
but nothing else.
I use ubuntu server so no gui at all.
In one machine i am running a proxy and I am trying to easy start and stop it without typing long lines, to start it I created a .sh file and I can start it easy enough but once it runs, I have to enter the screen windows where it's running, type Ctrl-C and after few second start it again. Is any way to automate it?

To run it I type this long line:

```
sudo java -jar myprogram.jar -f /home/franco/operations/proxy/switcher/prx1/setting.conf
```

I made a script called `prx1.sh` to start it using screen:

```
cd /home/franco/operations/startup
su franco -c "screen -dmS prx1 ./prx1.sh"
```

This works fine and fast to start it but sometimes I need to stop it and restart. Here is where I am failing.
I have to get the screen, type ctrl-C and then call my script again to restart.

Is any possibility to make a script to automate it?

I hope I make sense

Comment: Thanks @muru for editing my question

Comment: As I didn't get any suggestion I think my question is silly and there is no way to use kill, pkill or killall without grabbing the PID?