# Running BaseX as an upstart job

Tags: server, upstart, services

I'm trying to configuring [BaseX](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Main_Page) to run as a service on my server. The `basexserver` command has a flag `-S` whose functionality is listed as "start as service".

If I run `basexserver -S` at the command line, it outputs `Server was started.` and returns to the shell prompt, with the server running as a background process. If I then run `basexserver stop`, it outputs `Server was stopped.` and returns to the shell prompt, with the server process no longer running.

Now I want to make this into an upstart job (something which is new to me). I'm not clear on how to translate this start-and-stop interface into an upstart job, particularly with respect to the expect stanza. The Upstart Cookbook [recommends a procedure](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#how-to-establish-fork-count) for establishing the fork count of an application; this yielded the number 34, which is well outside the range of expected results.  What's the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

[basexserver](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Start_Scripts#Linux.2FMac:_basex) is a bash script. Instead of calling provided bash script you should translate it to Upstart job. The article [EVENTING UPSTART](http://javacruft.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/eventing-upstart/) will give you good ideas how to do it.

I would start crafting Upstart job with a simple Upstart stanza `exec java -cp BaseX.jar org.basex.BaseXServer`. See [Starting java processes with Upstart](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162768/starting-java-processes-with-upstart) for more details.

Comment: Are you saying the upstart job can't use `basexserver` to start and stop the process? Other upstart jobs that I've looked at seem to do it that way when such a script exists.

Comment: Which process is controlling basex? bash (basexserver) of Java (one started by bash script)? basexserver will start Java process which would continue running as daemon. At that point Upstarts louse control over Java process. I digged a bit and found basexserver script in launchpad: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-branches/ubuntu/saucy/basex/saucy/view/head:/debian/scripts/basexserver I seriously doubt that Upstart can controll that script. I am assuming that you installed basex from the Ubuntu repository.